# how to create a group from a dataframe?

Tags: pandas

This is my input dataframe:

```
index_x index_y date_of_invoice amount_x amount_y
  171     257    2019-01-10      57375    -57375
  171     258    2019-01-10      57375    -57375
  172     257    2019-01-10      57375    -57375
  172     258    2019-01-10      57375    -57375
  966     731    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  966     732    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  966     733    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  966     734    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  967     731    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  967     732    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  967     733    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  967     734    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  969     731    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  969     732    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  969     733    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  969     734    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  970     731    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  970     732    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  970     733    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  970     734    2019-02-13      3542.4   -3542.4
  980     700    2019-02-14      3542.4   -3542.4
  980     701    2019-02-14      3542.4   -3542.4
  981     700    2019-02-14      3542.4   -3542.4
  981     701    2019-02-14      3542.4   -3542.4
```

From this, I want to create a tuple like

```
(171, 172, 257, 258)
(966, 967, 969, 970, 731, 732, 733, 734)
(980, 981, 700, 701)
```

Here, group is decided based on both amount column

```
  980     700    2019-02-14      3542.4   -3542.4
  980     701    2019-02-14      3542.4   -3542.4
  981     700    2019-02-14      3542.4   -3542.4
  981     701    2019-02-14      3542.4   -3542.4
```

The last four cases date is different, but amount is same. so, we should consider that as a separate group

I tried with drop_duplicates and duplicated to get the tuple, but I am not getting the expected result.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the logic here? How do you group (171, 172, 257, 258) and (966, 967, 969, 970, 731, 732, 733, 734) apart?

Comment: @mozway It is index_x and index_y of two dataframe, merged on common column(here amount). Pandas merge created combination of index_x and index_y. That is the combination, I am giving here as input dataframe. I tried with groupby index_x, but it will create two groups

Comment: @mozway then I tried with drop_duplicates and duplicated to get unique values, from that, I thought of creating new tuple

Comment: I did not understand. Is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68364938/16343464) what you need? If not can you edit your question to provide the expected output?

Comment: I will update the question @mozway

Comment: updated the question, is my requirement clear? or do I need to add some more? @mozway

Comment: Basically, you want to group by date_of_invoice? See if my updated answer is what you need.

Comment: This is what I want, thanks man @mozway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach to group by 'date_of_invoice' and get the unique indexes of combined 'index_x' and 'index_y' in order:

```
(df.groupby('date_of_invoice')
   .apply(lambda d: tuple(pd.unique(d[['index_x', 'index_y']].values.reshape(-1, order='F'))))
)
```

output Series:

```
date_of_invoice
2019-01-10                        (171, 172, 257, 258)
2019-02-13    (966, 967, 969, 970, 731, 732, 733, 734)
2019-02-14                        (980, 981, 700, 701)
```